# Linear programming problem and Newtonian mechanics

Tags: linear-programming, integer-programming, operations-research

I am trying to learn Linear Programming. However, I don’t know how to solve the following problem. Maybe you can help, because I am curious to the right approach and solution for this problem. It involves Newtonian mechanics.

> [image]
>
> A company uses a crane for lifting (see picture). The crane has $2$ hoists. They can work at the same time. Both ends can take $10000 \,\rm N$. If the two hoist both pick 1 artefact at the same time, what is the maximum force that the first hoist can take?
>
> - The force on hoist $1$ is represented by $x$.
> - The force on hoist $2$ is $9000 \,\rm N$.
> - The position of hoist $1$ is fixed.
> - The position of hoist $2$ is not fixed, as long as it is to the right of the first hoist.
>
> The distance between both hoist is represented by $y$.

Answer (score 0):

A force $z$ down at position $a$ from the left will exert a force of $\frac{40-a}{40}z$ on the left support and $\frac{a}{40}z$ on the right.

The force distribution of hoist 2 does not change that the force acts on the crane effectively at the same center position. Thus you get **inequalities**
$$
10\,000 \ge \frac{35}{40}⋅x+\frac{32-y}{40}⋅9000\\
10\,000 \ge \frac{5}{40}⋅x+\frac{8+y}{40}⋅9000
$$
you get the geometry constraint
$$
0\le y\le 29
$$
and you want of course **maximize $x$.**

Graphically the maximum is at $y=29$ with $x=\frac{40⋅10\,000-3⋅9000}{35}=10657.142857$

[image: plot of the constraints]

Comment: From an Integer Linear Programming perspective, how do I formulate the objective function for this problem? Such as: Max z  5(x1 + y1 + x2) - 2(y1).

Answer (score 0):

Calling $V_1, V_2$ the vertical reactions al left and right, and considering that the supporting beam length is $40$ we have

$$
\max x \ \ \text{s. t. }
\cases{
0 \le y \le 29\\
0\le V_1\le 10000\\
0\le V_2\le 10000\\
V_1+V_2 = x + 9000\\
5x + (y+8)9000 -40 V_2 = 0
}
$$

The solution is

$$
\cases{
x = 10657.14\\
y = 29\\
V_1 = 10000\\
V_2 = 9657.14
}
$$